# can someone open linked question?

Tags: discussion

Can someone open linked question. I havw the picture changed.
[transformer capactive](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648240/transformer-capactive)

Comment: Your question still is in a very sad state. Show us that you value _our_ time by formatting your question properly. I'm not going to read that blurry mess. And neither am I going to rotate my head.

Comment: @VelVel if i can read this and you cant? You gotta phone that can surf the web right?

Comment: @VelVel point out what you cant read. You say your having difficulty with my question be specific use your big words. Some of the text is irrelivant. Use your phone and click on the pictures and you have a clearer picture.

Comment: Rather than dumping a (poor) picture of a book on top of unpaid volunteers and ask them to do all the work, the one asking the question is the one who should put in some effort here. For example the site has a built-in schematics tool, so you could quite trivially redraw the circuit there. Also, no phone in the world can increase the quality of the picture, you can just zoom it. And the majority of the site users view it through a PC, not through a phone. But the point here is rather that you shouldn't be posting photos of text (books) in the first place...

Answer (score 9):

This ended up being too long for a comment:

If you want your question re-opened, then listen to what people are saying. People are literally telling you what to do and you're just being rude to them? That won't help.

Not everyone uses a phone, so telling people to turn their phone sideways in a rude way will make it incredibly unlikely anyone will bother spending any time with you. If I see a question that has hardly any text, a huge blurry picture and a sideways one, I'm gonna downvote and move on. I'm not wasting time on that.

To get your question re-opened, use the schematic editor built in here, draw the relevant schematic and ask the question you want the answer to. Type out the bits of the book that ARE relevant instead of posting a bunch of irrelevant text (your words). Bottom line? Put the effort in. If you don't, no one will.